# How to copy sublist lines to a new transaction

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I would like to copy a few lines of the sales order "item" sublist and insert them into another sales order.

For now I have just found `N/record.insertLine(sublistId, lineNr, ignoreRecalc)`, but I can't see how this function could help me because it doesn't take any data.

My use case is that I have a sales order out of which I have to generate other sales orders, but only containing some of the items of the original sales order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need these two to work with.

```
Get Sublist
...
var objField = objRecord.getSublistField({
 sublistId: 'item',
 fieldId: 'item',
 line: 3
});    

Set Sublist

objRecord.setSublistValue({
     sublistId: 'item',
     fieldId: 'item',
     line: 3,
     value: true
    });
```